# Is it possible to turn the kubernetes feature on in docker-for-windows with automation?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, docker-for-windows, docker

I am working on an [ansible based dev-bootstrap project](https://github.com/lucastheisen/dev-bootstrap).  I'd like to be able to [enable the kubernetes](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#kubernetes) from the [docker role](https://github.com/lucastheisen/dev-bootstrap/blob/master/roles/docker/tasks/windows.yml), but i cant seem to find a way to do so.  I searched the registry for `docker` and `kubernetes`, nothing jumped out.  I also checked for a [daemon.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon#configure-docker-with-configuration-file), but none is present even though i have kubernetes enabled (manually).  Does anyone know if there is a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is all you need, but when toggling the enable Kubernetes option it writes to the settings.json. There is also a Kubernetes Initial install step, so this might not be enough, but I would try see if it picks it up, needs a restart or doesn't work at all...

```
function Enable-DockerKubernetes {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ()
    try {
        $settings = "$env:AppData\Docker\settings.json"
        $dockerSettings = ConvertFrom-Json ( Get-Content $settings  -Raw -ErrorAction Stop)
        if (!$dockerSettings.KubernetesEnabled) {
            Write-Verbose ("Enabling Kubernetes in {0}." -f $settings)
            $dockerSettings.KubernetesEnabled = $true
            $dockerSettings | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $settings -ErrorAction Stop 
        }
        else {
            Write-Verbose "Already enabled!"
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error $_
    }
}
```

The installer for Docker CE doesn't seem to support passing in installer options according to this issue which just went stale and got closed.

You might want to open a new issue specifically about this use case.

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1322